# ajax loading progress animation

Tags: jquery

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#demo_content').html('<img src="/ajax-loader.gif"alt="Wait" />');

        $('#demo_content').load('/myphp.php?nice=1149632');
          $("#demo_content").html('');
        return false;
        cache:false

    });
});
```

This script will load my data into the page but I cannot get my loader image to display while the ajax is loading. Can anyone give me advice as to how I would edit this to function correctly?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$("#demo_content").html('');` line removes the image immediately before it's displayed. You should remove it and try again.

Comment: wow thank you so much i got it to work exactly how i wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

$(function(){
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#demo_content').html('');

            $('#demo_content').load('/myphp.php?nice=1149632');
            return false;
            cache:false
        });
    });